# Randomly generate 1 or -1 (positive or negative integer)

Tags: python, random

I wanted to generate 1 or -1 in `Python` as a step to randomizing between non-negative and non-positive numbers or to randomly changing sign of an already existing integer. What would be the best way to generate 1 or -1 in `Python`? Assuming even distribution I know I could use:

```
import random

#method1
my_number = random.choice((-1, 1))

#method2
my_number = (-1)**random.randrange(2)

#method3
# if I understand correctly random.random() should never return exactly 1
# so I use "<", not "<="
if random.random() < 0.5:
    my_number = 1
else:
    my_number = -1

#method4
my_number = random.randint(0,1)*2-1
```

Using `timeit` module I got the following results:

```
#method1
s = "my_number = random.choice((-1, 1))"
timeit.timeit(stmt = s, setup = "import random")
>2.814896769857569
#method2
s = "my_number = (-1)**random.randrange(2)"
timeit.timeit(stmt = s, setup = "import random")
>3.521280517518562
#method3
s = """
if random.random() < 0.5: my_number = 1
else: my_number = -1"""
timeit.timeit(stmt = s, setup = "import random")
>0.25321546903273884
#method4
s = "random.randint(0,1)*2-1"
timeit.timeit(stmt = s, setup = "import random")
>4.526625442240402
```

So unexpectedly method 3 is the fastest. My bet was on method 1 to be the fastest as it is also shortest. Also both method 1 (since `Python 3.6` I think?) and 3 give the possibility to introduce uneven distributions. Although method 1 is shortest (main advantege) for now I would choose method 3:

```
def positive_or_negative():
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1
```

Testing:

```
s = """
import random
def positive_or_negative():
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1
        """
timeit.timeit(stmt = "my_number = positive_or_negative()", setup = s)
>0.3916183138621818
```

Any better (faster or shorter) method to randomly generate -1 or 1 in `Python`? Any reason why would you choose method 1 over method 3 or vice versa?

Comment: Method 3 is fastest because all the other methods have to do something like that internally.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A one liner variation of #3:

```
return 1 if random.random() < 0.5 else -1
```

It's fast(er) than the 'math' variants, because it doesn't involve additional arithmetic.

Answer (score 13):

Here's another one-liner that my timings show to be faster than the if/else comparison to 0.5:

```
[-1,1][random.randrange(2)]
```

Comment: I tested this - it is not faster. `timeit.timeit(stmt = "my_number = 1 if random.random() < 0.5 else -1", setup = "import random")` `>0.17129717730503558` and `timeit.timeit("my_number = [-1,1][random.randrange(1,2)]",setup= "import random")` `>2.5639535604734647`

Comment: @Siemkowski Your range specification is different than mine, and there may be differences between various versions of Python.

Comment: sorry, pasted wrong line, but it is still slower for me. I use `Python 3.6.1`. What version did you test it on?

Comment: @Siemkowski Python 2.7.10 on MacOS.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this code. Don't care about the difference in performance as much in my scenario - thanks! (:

Answer (score 7):

not sure what your application is exactly, but I needed something similar for a large vectorized array.

Here's a good way to get a sign array:

> (2*np.random.randint(0,2,size=(your_size))-1)

The result is an array, for example:

> array([-1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1])

and you can use the reshape command to get the above to the size of your matrix:

> (2*np.random.randint(0,2,size=(m*n))-1).reshape(m,n)

Then you can multiply a matrix by the above and get all of the members with random signs.

> A= np.array([[1, 2, 3],
>          [4, 5, 6]])
>
> B = A*(2*np.random.randint(0,2,size=(2*3))-1).reshape(2,3)

Then you get something like :

> B = array([[ 1,  2, -3],[ 4,  5, -6]])

Pretty quick, if your data is vectorized.

Answer (score 6):

Maths made simple:

1. Generate random number: 0 or 1
2. Get them mutiplied by 2: 0 or 2
3. Substract 1: -1 or 1

Adapt that to any programming code. No need for test functions.

```
print(random.randint(0,1)*2-1)
```

works also without randint

```
print(int(random.random()*2)*2-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to generate random numbers if you're going to be doing lots of them is by using numpy:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import random

In [3]: %timeit [random.choice([-1,1]) for i in range(100000)]
10 loops, best of 3: 88.9 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit [(-1)**random.randrange(2) for i in range(100000)]
10 loops, best of 3: 110 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit [1 if random.random() < 0.5 else -1 for i in range(100000)]
100 loops, best of 3: 18.4 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit [random.randint(0,1)*2-1 for i in range(100000)]
1 loop, best of 3: 180 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit np.random.choice([-1,1],size=100000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.52 ms per loop
```

Comment: At least the last one doesn't only return -1,+1.

Comment: isn't the last one (7) equivalent to `random.choices([-1,1], k=100000)` in `random` module?

Comment: @Siemkowski There was an edit, and the comment above referred to (8) i suppose.

Comment: @sascha I know, I am referring to (7)

Comment: Yes it is. But python's random module is not numpy's random module.

Answer (score 1):

If you need single bits (one per call), you already did your benchmark and other answers provide additional info.

If you need many bits or can pre-calculate bit-arrays for later consumption, numpy's methods *might* shine.

Here is some more **demo-approach** using numpy (which surprisingly does not have a method dedicated for this job exactly):

```
import numpy as np
import random

def sample_bits(N):
    assert N % 8 == 0  # demo only
    n_bytes = N // 8

    rbytes = np.random.randint(0, 255, dtype=np.uint8, size=n_bytes)
    return np.unpackbits(rbytes)

def alt(N):
    return np.random.choice([-1,1],size=N)

def alt2(N):
    return [1 if random.random() < 0.5 else -1 for i in range(N)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("sample_bits(1024)", setup="from __main__ import sample_bits", number=10000))
    print(timeit.timeit("alt(1024)", setup="from __main__ import alt", number=10000))
    print(timeit.timeit("alt2(1024)", setup="from __main__ import alt2", number=10000))
```

Output:

```
0.06640421246836543
0.352129537507486
1.5522800431775592
```

The general idea is:

- use numpy to generate many uint8's in one step

  - (there might be something better using internal functions without the randint-API)
- unpack uint8's to 8 bits

  - uniformity follows from randint's uniformity guarantees

Again, this is only a demo:

- for one specific case
- not caring about different result-types of these functions
- not caring about -1 vs. 0 (might be important in your use-case)
- (not even optimal compared to much more low-level approaches; MT used internally can be used as a bit-source, which does not need fp-math, like many other PRNGs!)

Answer (score 0):

random.randrange(-1,3,2)
prints a random number -1 or 1.
Remember "import random".
Explanation: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_randrange.asp

Answer (score -4):

My code is as

```
vals = array("i", [-1, 1])

def my_rnd():
    return vals[randint(0, 7) % 2]
```

Comment: Why use `randint(0, 7) % 2` instead of just `randint(0, 1)`?

Comment: My test shows this slower than all the OP's options.